# PHP: How would I remove parts of a string between 2 chunks of characters without removing too much?

Tags: php

This problem is driving me nuts. Let's say I have a string:

```
This is a &start;pretty bad&end; string that I want to &start;somehow&end; display differently
```

I want to be able to remove the &start; and &end; parts as well as everything in between so it says:

```
This is a  string that I want to  display differently
```

I tried using preg_replace with a regular expression but it took off too much, ie:

```
This is a  display differently
```

The question is: how do I remove the stuff just between sets of &start; and &end; pairs and make sure that it doesn't remove anything between any &end; and &start; segments?

Keep in mind, I'm working with hundreds of strings that are very different to each other so I'm looking for a flexible solution that'll work with all of them.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Edit: Replaced dollar signs with ampersands. Oops!

Comment: What RE did you try? It is important to either exclude the $ from the matched string or to at least search it non-greedy.

Comment: @eckes I tried this but it did what I said in the question (took too much off): `/\&start;[^>]+\&end;/`

Comment: `[^$]+?` excludes the $. (No idea if Dollar or ampersand is right, you mentioned both). And if you add ? It would even be non-greedy (but one of both is enough)

Comment: @eckes Oops! They were supposed to all be ampersands.

Comment: Post your `regex`. It is probably almost good, all you have to do is to add a `?` after `*` (or `+`) to make it not greedy.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex `/\&start;(.+?)\$end;/g`

It looks like it works as desired: https://regex101.com/r/MW5nom/2

Comment: I had just modified the Users regex. It seems to work with `\&` however you are correct, I believe it could just be `&`

Answer (score 1):

I quickly tried it on chrome console using JS, tried converting it into PHP:

```
"This is a &start;pretty bad$end; string that I want to &start;somehow$end; display differently".replace(/\&start;(.+?)\$end;/g, "")
```